# Error Channel — bad newest block expected status 200 got 403, channel mychannel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I am exploring Hyperledger Fabric and programming using Golang and Fabric Java SDK. When I am running an example, (https://medium.com/@lkolisko/hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java-basics-tutorial-a67b2b898410), I am facing the following error

> “Error Channel — bad newest block expected status 200 got 403, channel mychannel”

I tried to search for this error, but could not find anything relevant. Can you shed some light on this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but once I deleted and regenerated the *.jso files the sample runs fine. Hope this helps.